# How to save binary data from a XML response using XMLSpy or SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui, xmlspy

I'm using XMLSpy and SoapUI and making a web services (ws) call to Fedex to generate a label.   The response back from Fedex is a PNG or PDF file embedded in a web services response.  How can I save that the PNG/PDF element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goal, you need a way to decode base64.

1) Download Notepad++
2) Use the MIME Tool Plugin to convert

2a) Cut and paste the binary data from the web services call into a new file
2b) Plugin -> MIME Tool -> Base64 Decode
2c) Save the file as PNG or PDF (depending on what data you're expecting

3) Open PNG or PDF in browser